# Вырезать текст после определенного слова

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Помогите пожалуйста с регулярными выражениями. Есть строка

```
: ‚ь в_Инспекции ФНС России по Первореченскому району г.Владивостока код [2 151318 *ё
инн — [2]5]3]18 1]2ТоГо]7[4]5 0]
```

Нужно получить цифры после 'инн —'

Comment: Нужны только цифры или всё что после инн -? А как быть с 2ТоГо? Здесь тоже есть цифра

Comment: @razrab345 Приветствуем Вас на ruSO! На всякий случай, как для нового участника, Вы теперь можете ставить не только зелёные галочки, но и поблагодарить плюсом за ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let sSTR = `: ‚ь в_Инспекции ФНС России по Первореченскому району г.Владивостока код [2 151318 *ё
инн — [2]5]3]18 1]2ТоГо]7[4]5 0]`;

console.log(sSTR.replace(/[\s\S]+инн(.+)/gi, '$1').replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
```